# Given a multi-dimensional array, return an array containing the sum of the diagonals

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, math

Given a multi-dimensional array, return an array containing the sum of the diagonals.

For example:

```
input:
  [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
  ]

output:

[ 7, 12, 15, 8, 3 ]
```

```js
function addDiagonals(matrix) {
  let sum = 0;
  let j = matrix[0].length - 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++, j--) {
    sum += matrix[i][j];
    sum += matrix[i][i];
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(addDiagonals([
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
]));
```

I am able to find the sum of the diagonals. But I need to know how to go about finding the sum of each diagonal.

But I need to complete this:

```js
function diagonalSum(matrix) {
  let sum = 0;
  let res = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    let j = matrix.length - i - 1;

    res[i] = matrix[i][j];



    console.log(`i = ${i} and j = ${j};`)
  }
  return res;
}
console.log(diagonalSum([
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
]));
```

Comment: from my point of view this is more likely a math problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an initial array of numbers (for the diagonal sums) first, then use `reduce` to iterate, using the x index and y index together with the array length to figure out the proper diagonal index the current number should be added to:

```js
const input = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
];

const { length } = input;
const initial = new Array(length * 2 - 1).fill(0);
const output = input.reduce((a, subArr, y) => {
  subArr.forEach((item, x) => {
    const diagIndex = x - y + length - 1;
    a[diagIndex] += item;
  });
  return a;
}, initial);

console.log(output);
```

Another example with a 4x4 array:

```js
const input = [
  [1, 2, 3, 9],
  [4, 5, 6, 9],
  [7, 8, 9, 9],
  [2, 2, 2, 2]
];

const { length } = input;
const initial = new Array(length * 2 - 1).fill(0);
const output = input.reduce((a, subArr, y) => {
  subArr.forEach((item, x) => {
    const diagIndex = x - y + length - 1;
    a[diagIndex] += item;
  });
  return a;
}, initial);

console.log(output);
```

The derivation of

```
const diagIndex = x - y + length - 1;
```

is: as `y` (column index) increases, if `x` (row index) stays the same, `diagIndex` should decrease, as you're getting closer to the bottom left corner and index 0 of the output sum array. So, on the right hand side of `const diagIndex =`, `y` is negative. As `x` increases, if `y` stays the same, `diagIndex` should increase, since you're getting farther away from the bottom left corner, so `x` is positive on the right-hand side.

We now have

```
const diagIndex = x - y + num;
```

where `num` is something else

We also know that at `x = 0` and `y = <square length - 1>` (bottom left corner), the diagonal index should be 0, so:

```
diagIndex = x - y + num;
0 = 0 - (length - 1) + num
length - 1 = num
```

Plug that in:

```
const diagIndex = x - y + num;
const diagIndex = x - y + (length - 1);
```

Comment: Judging by the nature of the question, Jonnie is a beginner. I think he could benefit from some more detailed explanation of the math behind this code. I don't expect the line `diagIndex = y - x + length - 1` to be obvious to a novice.

Comment: @SergGr yes but just like i wrote in my comment below the question this is more likely a math problem and should be discussed at https://mathoverflow.net/ - so i guess this answer is more than enough for SO :)

Comment: @messerbill, I disagree with you and it looks like not that many people here agree with you (but some do). IMHO this is a perfectly valid practical question. I don't think that from the math's point of view the trick used in this answer makes any sense but it makes a great sense in the practical programming world.

Comment: Yep, as this is StackOverflow, the answer is all about *getting the proper desired output* for each legitimate input through code, and not about theoretically and soundly proving anything mathematical about matricies.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Its not that I am a beginner, I just could not wrap my head around it for some reason. But I guess it makes sense.

Comment: @Jonnie I had no idea about it either, I just reasoned that: as X increases, index increases, and Y increases, index decreases, and the length is also relevant, then I guessed and checked until the required output was obtained, and then reasoned my way backwards from there to examine *why* it works :P

Comment: I was asked to white board this during an interview a few years ago and it has been stuck in my head.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume, just for now, that your current input is:

```
const input = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
];
```

Now, imagine we are placed on the last array of that matrix (i.e the array with `[7, 8, 9]`) and while iterating through indexes `[0..4]` (yea, from 0 to 4) of this array we trace a diagonal from the `bottom-rigth` to the `top-left`. So, the first and the last diagonal will be defined by the next elements:

```
First Diagonal: input[2][0] -> input[1][-1] -> input[0][-2]
Last  Diagonal: input[2][4] -> input[1][3] -> input[0][2]
```

Now, suppose we map the `undefined` values that results of accessing the not defined indexes of those arrays to the number `0`. Then, the sequences obtained from this approach will be:

```
(Diagonal 1): 7 -> 0 -> 0 => Sum = 7
(Diagonal 2): 8 -> 4 -> 0 => Sum = 12
(Diagonal 3): 9 -> 5 -> 1 => Sum = 15
(Diagonal 4): 0 -> 6 -> 2 => Sum = 8
(Diagonal 5): 0 -> 0 -> 3 => Sum = 3
```

I hope you have understood to this point because the next logic takes this approach for get the sum of the diagonals.

```js
const input1 = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
];

const input2 = [
    [1, 2, 3, 9],
    [4, 5, 6, 9],
    [7, 8, 9, 9],
    [2, 2, 2, 2]
];

const getDiagonalsSums = (matrix) =>
{
    let len = matrix.length;
    let dSums = new Array(len * 2 - 1).fill(0);

    for (var i = 0; i < dSums.length; i++)
    {
        for (var j = len - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            dSums[i] += (matrix[j][i + j - len + 1] || 0);
        }
    }
    
    return dSums;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getDiagonalsSums(input1)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(getDiagonalsSums(input2)));
```